# sending data to javascript worker

Tags: javascript, php, web-worker

I have an JS worker like this:

```
    function ler_valores()
    {
        self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
            var data = e.data;
            //verifica se existem dados e se não existe mais do que um destinatário
            if ( data.lista.indexOf(",") == -1 )
            {
                var dados = new FormData();
                dados.append( 'tipo', 'refresca_painel_mensagens' );
                dados.append( 'txtDe', data.lista );
                var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                xhttp.open( 'POST', "../ajax/mensagens.php", false );           
                xhttp.onload=function()
                {
                    postMessage( xhttp.responseText );
                }
                xhttp.send( dados);
                setTimeout( ler_valores,2000 );
            }   
            else
            {
                postMessage('');    
                setTimeout( ler_valores,2000 ); 
            }
        });

    }
    ler_valores();
```

and I call it on main php

```
function ativar_worker1 ( lista_destinatarios )
{
    var coisas = JSON.parse( '{"lista":"' + lista_destinatarios + '"}' );

    var worker = new Worker( '../worker/worker1_mensagens.js' );
    worker.postMessage( coisas );
    setTimeout(function() worker.postMessage( coisas );,2000);
    worker.onmessage = function( event )
    {
        $('ul.list-unstyled').append(event.data );
        console.log(event.data);
    };
}
```

With both ways, seting timeout I cant get a refresh data on ul.list-unstyled
How can I pass every 2 seconds the var coisas (things in english) to thw worker?
Many thanks!

Comment: You can use a timed loop using `sleep()`.

Comment: You can't manipulate the DOM in a worker. See:
[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056922/is-there-a-way-to-create-out-of-dom-elements-in-web-worker)

Comment: You can't manipulate the DOM in a worker -> Didn't understood, my worker only posts a message to the main php postMessage( xhttp.responseText );... And it updates the ul, but only one time.