# How to animate algorithm steps using a recursive generator

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, generator

I built a boggle solver algorithm utilizing a recursive helper function.
It uses a trie data structure to quickly check if the existing prefix has any words in the dictionary or not.
I would like to animate every step of the algorithm to display how every word is being found in the HTML table, but cannot get it to work correctly.

Here is the algorithm:

```
const trie = '' // instantiated trie class (omitted for brevity)
const list = '' // imported dictionary (omitted for brevity)

// inputs are all the cells inside the table that hold the letters
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
// size is the size of the table (ex. 4x4, 8x8, etc...)
const size = document.getElementById("size").valueAsNumber;

// populating the trie with every word in the dictionary
for (let item of list) {
  trie.insert(item);
}

const movements = (i, j) => [
  { row: i, column: j + 1, move: "RIGHT" },
  { row: i + 1, column: j + 1, move: "BOTTOM_RIGHT" },
  { row: i + 1, column: j, move: "BOTTOM" },
  { row: i + 1, column: j - 1, move: "BOTTOM_LEFT" },
  { row: i, column: j - 1, move: "LEFT" },
  { row: i - 1, column: j - 1, move: "TOP_LEFT" },
  { row: i - 1, column: j, move: "TOP" },
  { row: i - 1, column: j + 1, move: "TOP_RIGHT" },
];

// takes a 2D array as input (ex. [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']])
export const findWords = (matrix) => {
  const words = [];
  const iterate = (i, j, word, visited) => {
    if (matrix[i] && matrix[i][j]) {
      if (!visited[`${i}_${j}`]) {
        visited[`${i}_${j}`] = true;
        word += matrix[i][j];
        if (trie.find(word).length) {
          if (trie.contains(word)) {
            words.push(word);
          }
          const moves = movements(i, j);
          for (let move of moves) {
            const { row, column } = move;
            iterate(row, column, word, { ...visited });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      iterate(i, j, "", {});
    }
  }
  return words;
};
```

A working app example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/Msiric/24x765bn/

Here is what the code looks like when using a generator:

```
export const findWords = (matrix) => {
  const words = [];
  const iterate = function* (i, j, word, visited, color) {
    if (matrix[i] && matrix[i][j]) {
      if (!visited[`${i}_${j}`]) {
        visited[`${i}_${j}`] = true;
        word += matrix[i][j];
        // highlighting the current cell here
        inputs[j + size * i].classList.add(color);
        if (trie.find(word).length) {
          if (trie.contains(word)) {
            words.push(word);
          }
          const moves = movements(i, j);
          for (let move of moves) {
            const { row, column } = move;
            yield* iterate(
              row,
              column,
              word,
              { ...visited },
              column % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red"
            );
            // the cell should be unhighlighted once this cell is done 
            inputs[j + size * i].classList.remove(color);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      iterate(i, j, "", {}, j % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red").next();
    }
  }
  return words;
};
```

Doing this just displays the final state of the algorithm which is not what I want.
I'd like to display each cell being highlighted or unhighlighted as every step is being executed and each word is being found.
I also tried including setTimeout functions to delay the execution of the helper function, but that didn't work either.
It just caused random flickering since cells were being highlighted/unhighlighted out of order.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/Msiric/jwag86o2/3/

The solution is partially inspired by Scott's suggestion, but since I couldn't get it to work, I found another way of specifying each step that should be performed when the animation is running.

Main changes to the algorithm:

```
const movements = (i, j) => [
  { row: i, column: j + 1, move: "RIGHT" },
  { row: i + 1, column: j + 1, move: "BOTTOM_RIGHT" },
  { row: i + 1, column: j, move: "BOTTOM" },
  { row: i + 1, column: j - 1, move: "BOTTOM_LEFT" },
  { row: i, column: j - 1, move: "LEFT" },
  { row: i - 1, column: j - 1, move: "TOP_LEFT" },
  { row: i - 1, column: j, move: "TOP" },
  { row: i - 1, column: j + 1, move: "TOP_RIGHT" },
];

const addStep = (() => {
  let counter = 1;
  return (i, j, matrix, isWord, action, steps) => {
    steps.push({
      x: i,
      y: j,
      c: matrix[i][j],
      isWord,
      action,
      counter,
    });
    action === "remove" ? counter-- : counter++;
  };
})();

const findWords = (matrix) => {
  const words = [];
  const map = {};
  const steps = [];
  const iterate = (i, j, word, visited) => {
    if (matrix[i] && matrix[i][j]) {
      if (!visited[`${i}_${j}`]) {
        visited[`${i}_${j}`] = true;
        word += matrix[i][j];
        addStep(i, j, matrix, false, "add", steps);
        if (trie.find(word).length) {
          if (trie.contains(word) && !map[word]) {
            words.push(word);
            map[word] = true;
            steps[steps.length - 1] = {
              ...steps[steps.length - 1],
              isWord: true,
            };
          }
          const moves = movements(i, j);
          for (let move of moves) {
            const { row, column } = move;
            iterate(row, column, word, { ...visited });
          }
          addStep(i, j, matrix, false, "remove", steps);
        } else {
          addStep(i, j, matrix, false, "remove", steps);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      iterate(i, j, "", {});
    }
  }
  return { words, steps };
};
```

And here is the visualization function:

```
const visualizeSteps = async (steps, inputs, spans, size) => {
  for (let step of steps) {
    const { x, y } = step;
    const selection = y + size * x;
    await delay(0);
    if (spans[selection].innerHTML === "") {
      spans[selection].innerHTML = step.counter;
    }
    inputs[selection].classList.add("highlight");
    if (step.isWord) {
      const highlights = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
      for (let highlight of highlights) {
        highlight.classList.add("success");
      }
      await delay(500);
      for (let highlight of highlights) {
        highlight.classList.remove("success");
      }
    } else {
      if (step.action === "remove") {
        await delay(0);
        inputs[selection].classList.remove("highlight");
        spans[selection].innerHTML = "";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you cannot render something while in the mid of a synchronous function. Any code which attempts to make DOM changes will only queue those changes, which cannot be drawn while the runtime is executing your synchronous function.

Hence, you have to make your function asynchronous, like in this example
https://jsfiddle.net/ep783cgw/2/

While I wasn't sure how you want to visualize it, I've made a renderState function which you can define to your liking.

```js
// modify it as per your liking
const renderState = (anim,i,j,move) => {
    const {row,column} = move
  anim.innerText = `${i}_${j}-${row}_${column}-${move.move}`
}

// show noticable delay in animation
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

// make findWords async
const findWords = async (matrix) => {
  const words = [];
  const anim = document.querySelector('#result');
  const iterate = async (i, j, word, visited) => {
    if (matrix[i] && matrix[i][j]) {
      if (!visited[`${i}_${j}`]) {
        visited[`${i}_${j}`] = true;
        word += matrix[i][j];
        if (trie.find(word).length) {
          if (trie.contains(word)) {
            words.push(word);
          }
          const moves = movements(i, j);
          for (let move of moves) {
            const { row, column } = move;
            // render the DOM
            renderState(anim,i,j, move);
            // wait for 200ms using await. Browser will draw the DOM in this time
            await delay(200);
            // iterate again using await
            await iterate(row, column, word, { ...visited });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      await iterate(i, j, "", {});
    }
  }
  return words;
};

// make handleSubmit async
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input");
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  const size = document.getElementById("size").valueAsNumber;
  const matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    const row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      row.push(inputs[j + size * i].value.toLowerCase());
    }
    matrix.push(row);
  }
  // use await to get output of findWords
  const words = await findWords(matrix);
  result.innerHTML = words;
};
```

To learn more, follow these links

1. [Event Loop Description | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
2. [A stackoverflow answer on similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685012/11218031)

EDIT: I just noticed that you aren't using generator function correctly.

To better utilize the generator function, you should create a single generator instance and call `next()` on it to yield all values. But in your code, you've written

```js
iterate(i, j, "", {}, j % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red").next();
```

where you're creating a new instance before every `.next()` call. Hence, the `iterate` generator won't yield all values.
The above line should therefore be

```js
const instance = iterate(i, j, "", {}, j % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red")
while(!instance.next().done)
```

You can read an example of generator functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit too much code for me to take in now.  But a general suggestion would be that you don't try to mix the algorithm with the display.

In the algorithm, keep track of the motions you test and their results.  Don't worry at all here about how you will display this.

After you've finished, take the test and one at a time, highlight the grid.  Here it's easy with either `setInterval` or chained `setTimeout`s, as you are simply iterating over a list of attempts.  Each time you would just need to unset current highlighting, and then set it for cells on the path, perhaps with a different display for the first and last cells of the path, and perhaps something different when you hit a legitimate word (animate the add to the list?)

Let's imagine we had a grid that in part looked something like this:

```
  \ x
y  \  0   1   2   3
    +---+---+---+---+
  0 | · | · | O | · |
    +---+---+---+---+
  1 | · | O | F | · |
    +---+---+---+---+
  2 | Z | L | · | H |
    +---+---+---+---+
  3 | · | I | S | · |
    +---+---+---+---+
```

Perhaps each test would yield something like

```js
{
  path: [{x: 2, y: 1, c: 'F'}, {x: 2, y: 0, c: 'O'}, {x: 1, y: 1, 'c': 'O'}], 
  stuck: false, 
  isWord: false
}
```

(assuming "FOO" is not in your dictionary.)

Then when, because you're not stuck, you eventually add `{x: 1, y: 2, c: 'L'}`, you will have `isWord: true` ("FOOL") and `stuck: false` (because the trie says that there are nodes under `F-O-O-L`).

```js
{
  path: [{x: 2, y: 1, c: 'F'}, {x: 2, y: 0, c: 'O'}, {x: 1, y: 1, 'c': 'O'}, 
         {x: 1, y: 2, c: 'L'}], 
  stuck: false, 
  isWord: true
}
```

But when you try instead to add `{x: 0, y: 2, c: 'Z'}`, and the trie tells you there are no words beginning `F-O-O-Z`, you can record that it's not a word and you are stuck.

```js
{
  path: [{x: 2, y: 1, c: 'F'}, {x: 2, y: 0, c: 'O'}, {x: 1, y: 1, 'c': 'O'}, 
         {x: 0, y: 2, c: 'Z'}], 
  stuck: true, 
  isWord: false
}
```

Eventually, you will try this this seven-letter word:

```
{
  path: [{x: 2, y: 1, c: 'F'}, {x: 2, y: 0, c: 'O'}, {x: 1, y: 1, c: 'O'}, 
         {x: 1, y: 2, c: 'L'}, {x: 1, y: 3, c: 'I'}, {x: 2, y: 3, c: 'S'}, 
         {x: 3, y: 2, c: 'H'}], 
  stuck: false, 
  isWord: true
}
```

Note that these can be the only output from your algorithm, because it's trivial to generate the word list from these tests:

```
  .filter (t => t .isWord) 
  .map (({path}) => path .map (n => n .c) .join (''))

const uniqueWords = [... new Set (words)]
```

## Major Update

I've been thinking about this on and off since I posted the above.  Here is an attempt to do it in something close to that fashion.  (It will probably look better if you use the "Full Screen" option of the snippet.):

```js
// *************************
// Main function
// *************************
const run = () =>
  Promise.resolve (showLoading())
    .then (getDictionary)
    .then (trie)
    .then (buildPuzzle)
    .then (tap (displayPuzzle))
    .then (solvePuzzle)
    // .then (tap (console .log))
    .then (displaySolution)
    .then (showWordCount)

// *************************
// Utility functions
// *************************
const tap = (fn) => (x) => (fn (x), x)
const range = (lo, hi) => [... Array (hi - lo)] .map ((_, i) => i + lo)
const last = (xs) => xs [xs .length - 1] 
const titleCase = ([c, ...cs]) => c .toUpperCase() + cs.join('')
const showLoading = () => // not really a utility function, but no place better
  document .getElementById ('word') .textContent ='Loading ...'

// *************************
// Dictionary handling -trie
// *************************
const getDictionary = () =>
  //fetch ('http://fourwindssoft.com/scott/words/')
  fetch ('https://norvig.com/ngrams/enable1.txt')
    .then (s => s .text ())
    .then (s => s .split ('\n'))

const trie = (words) => 
  words .reduce (insertWord, {}) 
const insertWord = (trie, [c, ...cs]) => 
  c ? {...trie, [c]: insertWord (trie [c] || {}, cs)} : {...trie, $: 1}
const find = (trie) => ([c = '', ...cs]) =>
  trie && (cs .length == 0 ? trie [c] : find (trie[c]) (cs))
const contains = (trie) => (word) =>
  '$' in (find (trie) (word) || {})


// *************************
// Board creation
// *************************
const buildPuzzle = (trie) => ({trie, letters: roll (dice)})
const dice = 
   'a|a|c|i|o|t, a|b|i|l|t|y, a|b|j|m|o|qu, a|c|d|e|m|p, a|c|e|l|r|s, a|d|e|n|v|z, a|h|m|o|r|s, b|i|f|o|r|x, d|e|n|o|s|w, d|k|n|o|t|u, e|e|f|h|i|y, e|g|k|l|u|y, e|g|i|n|t|v, e|h|i|n|p|s, e|l|p|s|t|u, g|i|l|r|u|w'
   .split (', ') .map (d => d.split ('|'))
const roll = (dice) => shuffle (dice) .map (pickOne)
const shuffle = (xs, i = Math .floor (Math .random () * xs .length)) =>
  xs .length == 0
    ? []
    : [xs[i], ... shuffle ([... xs .slice (0, i), ... xs .slice (i + 1)])]
const pickOne = (xs) => xs [Math .floor (Math .random () * xs .length)]


// *************************
// Initial display
// *************************
const displayPuzzle = ({letters}) =>
  letters .forEach ((l, i) => document .getElementById (`c${i}`) .textContent = titleCase (l))


// *************************
// Solving puzzle
// *************************
const solvePuzzle = ({trie, letters}) =>
  ({letters, tests: search (letters, neighbors, trie)})

// see https://link.fourwindssoft.com/30 for derivation or other grid sizes
const neighbors = 
  [[1, 4, 5], [0, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 6, 7], [0, 1, 5, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11], [2, 3, 6, 10, 11], [4, 5, 9, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14], [5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15], [6, 7, 10, 14, 15], [8, 9, 13], [8, 9, 10, 12, 14], [9, 10, 11, 13, 15], [10, 11, 14]]

const search = (letters, neighbors, words, path = []) => 
  path .length == 0
    ? letters .flatMap ((l, i) => search (letters, neighbors, find (words) (l) || {}, [i]))
    : [
        {path, isWord : words ? '$' in words && path.length > 2 : false, stuck: !words},
        ... neighbors [last (path)] 
              .filter ((i) => ! path .includes (i))
              .flatMap ((i) => words
                 ? search (letters, neighbors, find (words) (letters [i]), [...path, i])     
                 : []
              )
      ]

// *************************
// Display algorithm process
// *************************
const displaySolution = ({letters, tests}) => 
  showPaths (letters) (tests)

const showPaths = (letters) => ([t, ...ts]) => 
  t == undefined
    ? Promise.resolve(true)
    : showPath (letters) (t) .then (() => showPaths (letters) (ts))  

const showPath = (letters) => (t) => {
  document .getElementById ('word') .textContent = t.path .map (n => letters [n]) .join('')
  return highlightPath (50) (t.path)
    .then (() => {
      if (t.isWord) {
        document.getElementById ('board') .classList .add ('match')
      } else if (t.stuck) {
        document.getElementById ('board') .classList .add ('stuck')
      }
    })
    .then (delay (t.isWord ? 1500: 500) (clearHighlighting))
    .then (handleWord (t, letters))
    .then (() => {
      const classList = document.getElementById ('board') .classList 
      classList .remove ('stuck') 
      classList .remove ('match')
    })
  }

const highlightPath = (t) => (path) => seq (
  path .map ((n) => delay (t) (highlightCell (n)))
)

const seq = (promGens) =>
  promGens .reduce ((c, n) => c .then (n), Promise.resolve(true))

const delay = (time) => (thunk) => () => 
  new Promise ((res) => {setTimeout (() => {thunk(); res()}, time)})

const highlightCell = (n) => () =>
  document .getElementById (`c${n}`) .classList .add ('highlighted')

const clearHighlighting = () =>
  document .querySelectorAll ('#board td') .forEach ((node) => node .classList .remove ('highlighted'))


const handleWord = (t, letters) => {
  if (t.isWord) {
    const text = t.path .map (p => letters [p]) .join('')
    const match = [...document .querySelectorAll ('#found li')] .find (node => node .textContent == text)
    if (match) {
      match .scrollIntoView ()
      match .classList .add ('item-used')
      setTimeout (() => match .classList .remove ('item-used'), 6000) // uggh, 6000 should match css animation!
    } else {
      const li = document .createElement ('li')
      li. appendChild (document .createTextNode(text))
      document .getElementById('found') .appendChild (li)
      li .scrollIntoView ()
      li .classList .add ('item-highlight')
      setTimeout (() => li .classList .remove ('item-highlight'), 6000)
    }
  }
  return t
}

const showWordCount = () => // ugly to use the DOM for this info, but too much refactoring to fix
  document .getElementById ('word') .textContent = `${document.querySelectorAll('#found li') .length} words`


// *************************
// Start everything
// *************************
run ()
```

```css
table {background: #999; padding: .25em; border: 1px solid black;}
td {border: 1px solid black; padding: .25em; background: white; text-align: center; width: 1em; height: 1em;}
td.highlighted {background: #ccc;}
table.stuck, table.stuck td.highlighted {background: #f99;}
table.match, table.match td.highlighted {background: #9f9;}
pre {width: 10em; text-align: center; color: #666;}
code {font-size: 2em;}
.container {display: flex; flex-direction: row;}
#results {height: 10em; width: 8em; margin-left: .5em; padding: .5em; background: #ddd; overflow: auto;}
#results ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0em;}
@keyframes fadenew {from {background: #6f6} to {background: transparent;}}
li.item-highlight {animation: fadenew 6s;}
@keyframes fadeused {from {background: #f66} to {background: transparent;}}
li.item-used {animation: fadeused 6s;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="demo">
    <table id="board">
      <tr><td  id="c0">?</td><td  id="c1">?</td><td  id="c2">?</td><td  id="c3">?</td></tr>
      <tr><td  id="c4">?</td><td  id="c5">?</td><td  id="c6">?</td><td  id="c7">?</td></tr>
      <tr><td  id="c8">?</td><td  id="c9">?</td><td id="c10">?</td><td id="c11">?</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="c12">?</td><td id="c13">?</td><td id="c14">?</td><td id="c15">?</td></tr>
    </table>
    <pre><code id="word"></code></pre>
  </div>
  <div id="results">
    <ul id ="found"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did change slightly from my suggestion above.  The paths are just list of integers, indices into a flat array of letters that is the grid.  The list of neighbors of each index is hard-coded, although originally, when fiddling with different grid sizes, I [calculated them](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/30).

The code loads a dictionary, here Peter Norvig's [enable1](https://norvig.com/ngrams/enable1.txt) list, turns it into a trie, with the fairly simple `trie` function.  We randomly create a puzzle, using [simulated dice](http://www.bananagrammer.com/2013/10/the-boggle-cube-redesign-and-its-effect.html) that should be a close match to the original Boggle ones, display it (through the simple mapping of integer indices to cell ids), and use the fairly simple `search` function to find in it all the words that are in our dictionary and have at least three letters.  This will give us an array of results that look like this:

```js
[
  //...
  {path: [9, 5, 6, 3], stuck: false, isWord: true},
  {path: [9, 5, 6, 3, 2], stuck: true, isWord: false},
  //...
]
```

against the grid,

```
['L',' T',' P',' T',' O',' E',' N',' Y',' U',' T',' F',' O',' S',' H',' K',' I']
```

which represents the board

```
   +---+---+---+---+
   | L | T | P | T |
   +---+---+---+---+
   | O | E | N | Y |
   +---+---+---+---+
   | U | T | F | O |
   +---+---+---+---+
   | S | H | K | I |
   +---+---+---+---+
```

So `[9, 5, 6, 3]` represents `"TENT"` and `[9, 5, 6, 3, 2]` represents `"TENTP"`.

One interesting design decision here is to restrict the words to three or more letters in the solver rather than in the dictionary.  It is slightly less efficient, but I think visualizing the algorithm trying one and two letter words is clearer.

Now that we have this representation, we can demonstrate it by highlighting the path through each test case that we tried.  Note that the searcher stops when the trie does not contain the latest letter, so we don't have an exponential number of paths to search.  I assume all the other algorithms here do something similar.  There is no particularly interesting code in the display.  It simply, one at a time, highlights a path through the grid, briefly notes whether or not it's a word in our dictionary, and if it is one, checks to see whether we've already found it before adding it to a list of found words.  All this is done with plain DOM manipulation.  The only slight trickiness is in the timings of the animation.  We want to move quickly through our words, but want the animation of the words to be quick enough to show the actual path.  I'm not sure I've struck the right balance here, but it's not horrible.

One possible extension to this involves showing a progress bar of the trials we've displayed, or making it something that can be stopped, restarted and stepped through.  Another, very useful one would be to show the path with a line through the squares used and not just the highlight color.  But those are for another day.

A lot of the code is generic as to grid size, and using that [`getNeighbors`](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/30) function, we could easily make the rest of it so, except for one thing.  The dice we roll here are meant to simulate actual Boggle dice and not simple random selections.  It's not clear to me how to change that for larger grids.

---

This was a fun little thing to do.  While I hope it might help the OP, I was glad to do it just for my own amusement.