# Emscripten: Can't using emscripten::val in pthread

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I'm working on project to attach video from c++.

I have success create video element from c++.

```
video = emscripten::val::global("document").call<emscripten::val>("createElement", emscripten::val("video"));
video.set("src", emscripten::val("http://jplayer.org/video/webm/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.webm"));  
video.set("crossOrigin", emscripten::val("Anonymous"));
video.set("autoplay", emscripten::val(true));
video.call<void>("load");
```

But the problem came up is I have to wait until video buffer load enough to play.

My solution is using pthread to create thread wait until video buffer load enough and do stuff with the video.

```
 pthread_create(&threadVideo, NULL, attachVideo, NULL);
```

And inside attachVideo function

```
void *attachVideo(void *arg)
{
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    cout << "ready to run" << endl;
    cout << "readyState: " << video["readyState"].as<int>() << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

And when I run it cameout error: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')"**

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: perhaps, no way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056922/is-there-a-way-to-create-out-of-dom-elements-in-web-worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `emscripten::val` is represents an object in JS and the JS state is all thread local.  Another way of putting it: Each thread gets is own JS environment, so `emscripten::val` cannot be shared between threads.

Comment: I have found another solution that use timeout in js to check readyState and then call handle from js