# HTML processing in Service Worker without access to any foreground document?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, text-processing

So I am upgrading a Chrome extension to MV3 and the background page now becomes a `Service Worker`. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056922/is-there-a-way-to-create-out-of-dom-elements-in-web-worker) apparently there is no access to any DOM element. I need to upgrade this function that basically get an HTML snippet and get its text content:

```js
    const htmlStripper = document.createElement("template")
    const striphtml = html => {
        htmlStripper.innerHTML = html
        return htmlStripper.content.textContent
    }
```

I tried using `DocumentFragment` as well but it's also not available to Service Worker. Unlike the other question, I do not have access to any foreground HTML page so message passing is not possible as well.

What is a solution for this? Beside this specific problem (nice if I can solve this one), is there a generic solution for all kind of HTML processing we could have done as if we had access to a `document`?

---

For my specific case, this solution is good enough, stealing from [a C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154046/653457):

```js
    const striphtml = html => {
        return html.replace(/<.*?>/g, "").trim();
    }
```

Be warned that this is not perfect.

Comment: Use a `+` instead of `*` in the regexp to avoid replacing of `<>`.

Comment: @Akxe thanks for the suggestion. Applied the fix to my code though in my case the input unlikely has it (just a normal HTML request parsing)

Answer (score 2):

Off-screen document.
For now you can only do some testing in Chrome Canary.
You have to create first a browser shortcut to Chrome Canary with the command line option **--enable-features = ExtensionsOffscreenDocuments**

```
const myHtml = "<div>Ciao<span>amico</span>come <b id="foo">va?</b></div>";
await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: 'osd.html',
    justification: 'ignored',
    reasons: ['dom_scraping']
});
let hd = await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument();
if (hd) {
    let reply = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'html': myHtml});
    await chrome.offscreen.closeDocument();                         
    console.log(reply)
}

//manifest.json
...
"permissions": [
    ...
    "offscreen"
]
...

//osd.html
<html><head><script src="osd.js"></script></head></html>

//osd.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const htmlStripper = document.createElement("template")
    const striphtml = html => {
        htmlStripper.innerHTML = html
        return htmlStripper.content.textContent
    }
    sendResponse({'reply': striphtml(msg.html)})
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find any documentation on this. Is there any discussion thread for this? Any timeline when it will go into production? Unfortunately this answer is great but we can't apply this for our product right if it requires this special switch.

Comment: The documentation is scarce and not definitive.
Some code snippet here: [LINK](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/HEAD/chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/offscreen/basic_document_management/)  



Discussion thread on Google Group [LINK](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/PJPCn0_k5Pk/m/V7PBJgTLAQAJ)

Comment: Thank you, that doesn't look like it (or even doc) will be available any time soon. This whole process of deprecating MV2 is absurd...

Comment: it's a bit like the Davos agenda. "They" go on without looking anyone in the face

Comment: I cannot set the reason `dom_scripting`. 

I'm getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 
Error in invocation of offscreen.createDocument(offscreen.CreateParameters parameters, function callback): 
Error at parameter 'parameters': Error at property 'reasons': Error at index 0: Value must be one of TESTING.
`

Comment: it's a "working in progess" api...