# Downloading large pdf with html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf to download a PDF of my website. The downloaded PDF is 14 pages long. After about 12 pages I can see that the elements that had colors are no longer there. If I try to download the PDF on a mobile screen this starts even sooner at around 6 or 7th page. There are no colors anymore and some of the input elements are missing.

Is there a way for html2pdf to handle larger content?

This is my setting right now

```
var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
var opt = {
  margin:       0,
  filename:     'myfile.pdf',
  image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas:  { scale:1 },
  jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
};
html2pdf(element).set(opt)
```

I tried increasing the quality to 2 from 0.98 but nothing changes.

Comment: You should try this https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Comment: I am converting to PDF in the front end so I cannot do that

Comment: I've got the exact same problem, did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to download the file in the background without impacting user experience. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689932/how-to-apply-web-worker-to-rendering-of-a-pdf-using-makepdf) for a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the `scale` in the `html2canvas` option.
Helped me get the colors on all pages.